# Spring Web Socket with STOMP Issues

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, stomp, spring-websocket

I am working on WebSocket application with STOMP and RabbitMQ as the broker. It is a chat-like application. I tried to dump thousands of messages to check if the socket will crash or observe any flicker in the UI.

Javascript code:

```
for(let i=1;i<1000;i++)
{
   if (stompClient) {
      var chatMessage = {
         sender : name,
         content : "File Processing at "+i+ " %",
         type : 'Process'
      };
      stompClient.send("/app/chat.sendMessage", {}, JSON.stringify(chatMessage));       
   }
}
```

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot-websocket-chat).

Here is what I observed:

1. A fresh session will send and receive messages within seconds, but if I send again and again the time taken will increase every time 1s, 3s, 5s, & 20s up to 1 min 30s for same 1,000 messages.
2. After sending 4-5 times if it takes more than 30s. Once messages are received the WebSocket session is terminated, and sometimes flicker is observed.
3. Re-connecting to the WebSocket after timeout will again take longer than previous to send and receive, and flickering is observed. The UI gets stuck for a while.

I am very new to this concept. Can anyone tell me why is this happening and how to overcome this?